# Computing 3-term connection coefficients for wavelets

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, numerical-linear-algebra, wavelets

I am trying to calculate the three-term connection coefficients

$$
Λ_{l,m}^{d_1,d_2,d_3} = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \varphi^{(d_1)}(x) \varphi^{(d_2)}_l(x) \varphi^{(d_3)}_m(x) dx
$$

for Daubechies wavelets numerically using Python. [This report (p. 20)](https://www.nada.kth.se/utbildning/grukth/exjobb/rapportlistor/2004/rapporter04/besora_jordi_04091.pdf) gives a nice overview of how to calculate them.

I wrote a [(well documented) implementation](https://manuels.github.io/db_cc3/docs/cc3_2.html) in python and for the two-term connection coefficients had no problems but when I compare my 3-term results with the ones of Resnikoff and Wells (1998) I find lots of errors (only the $l=m$ coefficients appear to be correct).

I am starring at the code for weeks now, but I cannot find any errors. I would be very pleased if somebody would give me a hint where the error might be.

Comment: you will probably be better off asking at either StackOverflow or SciComp.stackexchange.com

Comment: I guess StackOverflow is really the wrong place, but I did not know about SciComp! I will give it a try. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since I also need to calculate connection coefficients with python I've tried some stuff to get your code working. I have put this script on my github (https://github.com/FalkoGiep/CC_Wavelets).

I have not kept track of what is wrong with your code, but the main difference are that I use scipy.linalg.lstsq instead of the numpy variant. Also I use a different expression for the moments.